# Copy files from ftp to docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

I have my application jar files available in FTP. I am not sure how to copy the file from FTP to tomcat instance running in docker container. I need to pass the FTP credentials to copy the file from FTP. I am new to docker and please provide with any example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a static copy, done once for all containers to use, that means those jars have to be copied in the *image*, with a [`COPY` directive](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in the dockerfile.

In that case, it is not good to include any credential in the Dockerfile itself.
It would be best to:

- wget or curl those jars first from ftp
- then COPY the local jars to the image

  ```
  COPY *.jar <dest>
  ```